# Forwarding e mails with Lotus Notes 8.5 on Mac OS X 10.7.4

Tags: macos, gmail, lotus-notes

I am using IBM Lotus Notes version 8.5 and I want to forward my emails to my gmail account; how do I do this? I can't find rules in this version. Is it because I have a Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the navigation area of your mailbox -- the left-hand pane on your screen.  You should see "Inbox", "Drafts", and "Sent" at the top, and "Tools" at the bottom.  Click on "Tools", and now you should see "Archive", "Rules" and "Stationery".  Click on "Rules", which should show you if there are already any rules defined for your main, then click on the "New Rule" button and follow the instructions listed under #2 in the first link that Per Henrik posted.  (Note: there should actually be a short-cut to the "New Rules" dialog on the Actions menu... but I think it's preferable to follow the navigator links, as that will show you any existing rules that might already be there.)

If you do not see things in the navigation pane as I described them, contact your system administrator.  Your mail database may need to be upgraded to a newer template, or there may be a policy in place that is blocking you.  (Not sure if there is a policy capability for that... I'm just guessing.)

One more thing: if there are rules in your mailbox, or if you create one and go back to it later... please remember to never, ever delete a rule without first disabling it.

Comment: Glad it helped. FYI, you could accept and upvote my answer so the system will give me a tiny little credit for being helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can forward mail creating a mail rule in your mail database (by using the "send copy to" action). See e.g. this document for more details on this:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21162404

An even better solution is to update your person document in the Domino Directory with your forwarding address. If you do not have access to update your own person document, then ask your administrator do update it for you. You can find more details about forwarding addresses here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_SETTING_UP_A_FORWARDING_ADDRESS_STEPS.html